# App Engine Unit Testing with nosetests gae issue

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, nosetests

I've been unit testing my application using `nosetests` with the `with-gae` plugin.

However, I've wrapped many of my get/post handlers with decorators that check certain items in the datastore and put them in os.environ for use in the handlers.

So I might have a decorator that does something like:

```
os.environ["user"] = User()
```

where User() is an ndb.Model instance. However, when I run nosetests, this will always fail and will give me an error like:

```
os.environ["user"] = user
File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 420, in __setitem__
   putenv(key, item)
TypeError: must be string, not User
```

I had a similar thread here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/1KR7UIPHoQM

I was told App Engine doesn't actually call getenv/putenv in the os module.

The error is because in Python's normal `os` module, you cannot insert anything but strings into `os.environ` and `nosetests` is using the regular Python `os` module apparently.

However, App Engine uses `request_environment.py` to handle `os.environ` calls.

How can I mitigate this so nosetests will behave with `os.environ` calls?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using the db stub (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting) to put your required entities on it just before testing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for anyone else who might encounter this problem: call `PatchOsEnviron` in `google.appengine.api.runtime` before running tests.